# Contributions not showing in github and email id not associated with each commit

Tags: git, github

In commits on my repo, only my name is being shown for commits which I did from command line using `git add .` , `git commit -m "msg"` and `git push -u origin master`and also these commits are not being shown in my contribution graph. For the commits, I did on github itself manually, my username is being displayed and those commits are counted in my contributions. Here is the link to those commit page : https://github.com/amangupta87/NodeJS/commits/master.

I went through the the article  https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/ for contributions being not shown on my profile.

I did run

```
git config --global user.email
git config --global user.name
```

Both the outputs were as expected and correct and were without quotes. The email output is also my primary email on github and there is no typo.

My email was private first and hence the default email was being shown as `35622296+amangupta87@users.noreply.github.com` instead of `amangupta87@users.nonreply.github.com` where `amangupta87` is my username. Then I made my emails public thinking that error might go, but it persists.

Then I added `.patch` to one of my commit link and then obtained the following output:

```
From e37d766e8786becb50d4b4080ac76ef13ca44b63 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Aman Gupta <my email address used on my git repo>
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2020 14:15:32 +0530
Subject: [PATCH] mongoDB

---
```

After this, the details of modified files were there.

As you might see, in the `From:` email address inside `<>` is `my email address used on my git repo` instead of my email address on github. So if this is the reason behind the problem, how to solve this? If not, then what is the problem and solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the output of `git config --global user.email` is correct, but that address is not what you see in your commits, then the local repo might have a different config, overriding the global one. What does `git config user.email` say (without the `--global`)?

Comment: @mmlr Thanks, it worked. It was actually showing no email id and then I changed it to my email id, then things worked fine. Thanks again.